# Beautify: Force line-break for every or specific tags

Tags: html, js-beautify

Is there an option to create a line-break for all or specific tags like i, span or img?

Given the following HTML input:

```
<button><i>span>Copy</span></i></button>
<div><img src="img1.png" alt="" /></div>
<div><img src="img2.png" alt="" /></div>
```

And here is the result i would like to have:

```
<button>
  <i>
    <span>Copy</span>
  </i>
</button>
<div>
  <img src="img1.png" alt="" />
</div>
<div>
  <img src="img2.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

I already tryed different settings of extra_liners:

```
"extra_liners" : ["img", "i", "span", "button"]
```

without the desired success.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried it myself because the task is colossal, but if you use [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), I think it's this way :  [Settings.md](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/blob/master/Settings.md).

`unformatted` : **List of tags that should not be reformatted.**

Default :

```
["a", "abbr", "area", "audio", "b", "bdi", "bdo", "br", "button", "canvas", "cite", "code", "data", "datalist", "del", "dfn", "em", "embed", "i", "iframe", "img", "input", "ins", "kbd", "keygen", "label", "map", "mark", "math", "meter", "noscript", "object", "output", "progress", "q", "ruby", "s", "samp", "select", "small", "span", "strong", "sub", "sup", "svg", "template", "textarea", "time", "u", "var", "video", "wbr", "text", "acronym", "address", "big", "dt", "ins", "strike", "tt"]
```

You'd have to remove `img`, `i`, `span` and `button` from this default list.